NEOS interface not returning solution
I am using the conopt solver through the NEOS interface to solve my model in a script. When I pass my model with 0 degrees of freedom to find a feasible initial point, the model is solved and returned to the script. But when I free up variables and add an objective function, it shows in the NEOS log that my submission was received and solves my model (I receive the email with the .sol file), but it does not return the results to my script. There is no error message that is asserted, the script just does not end as if it is stuck in a loop.
The model I am sending is fairly large (~21,000 variables and constraints), so I have tried to send a smaller model to NEOS using conopt and it returns with no issues. Is this an issue over the size of the model even though I get the results returned when I submit a square model?
Additionally, is there any method to load the .sol file back into the model, other than loading a Results object, to access values for specific decision variables?
Update: This issue was occurring on my home PC which is running on Windows 11. My work PC is running on Windows 10 and is not facing the same issue as I have not been able to reproduce it. Both environments have Pyomo v6.7.1 installed
